# Horizontal LinearLayout inside Vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-gravity

I want to display an horizontal linearlayout which content 3 imageview inside a vertical linearLayout

But i have a problem as you can see

[image]

Only the first Imageview is displayed , and he is in the center .

I changed the gravity for the other Imageview (left and right) but nothing changed .

The code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.FormActivity"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ajouter Votre Annonce"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:entries="@array/cat_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/cat_prompt"
            />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:text="Offre"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />



        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Demande"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:entries="@array/vil_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/vil_prompt"
            android:textColor="#808080"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Titre de l'Annonce"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Prix en UM"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"
            android:paddingBottom="75dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Vos Photos"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22sp"

            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/imgadd"
                android:gravity="left"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/imgadd"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/imgadd"
                android:gravity="right"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:text="Vos Informations"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:text="Professionel"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Particulier"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Nom et Prenom"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Telephone"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Mot de passe"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="Déposez votre Annonce"
            android:background="#a4c639"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/img1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight = "1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/imgadd"/>


   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/img2"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight = "1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/imgadd"/>

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/img3"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight = "1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/imgadd"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: happy to help you...!

Answer (score 1):

It can be fixed in multiple ways. What i would do is to assign layout_weight tag to all 3 images in the horizontal linear layout . something like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/imgadd"
        android:layout_weight ="1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight ="1"
        android:src="@drawable/imgadd"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight ="1"
        android:src="@drawable/imgadd"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Also remove the gravity tag in all three image views .

Comment: Should set width to `0dp`, though

Comment: your answer is valid too . Thx , but it should be android:layout_weight instead of android:weight , thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/imgadd"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/imgadd"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/imgadd"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:weight` is not android property, use `android:layout_weight`

Comment: Do you want the three pictures wrap the width? or you want the three pictures to be scrollable horizontally?